# Matrix proof question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A,B,C$ are $n\times n$ matrices and the matrix $ABC=I_n$. Show that $A,B, $ and $C$ are invertable matrices.
Not sure how to show $AA^{-1}=I_n$ $BB^{-1}=I_n$ $CC^{-1}=I_n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(AB)C = I_n$, so $C$ is invertible and its inverse is $AB$. As $AB$ is invertible, then both of $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

Answer (score 6):

$\operatorname{det}(ABC)=\operatorname{det}(A)\operatorname{det}(B)\operatorname{det}(C)=\operatorname{det}(I_n)=1$

So determinants of $A,B$ and $C$ are non zero hence, $A,B$ and $C$ are invertible

Answer (score 2):

**Without determinants:** $A,B,C$  are matrices of endomorphisms $f,g,h$ of $K^n$ (there's no information about the base field $K$). The hypothesis translates into $f\circ g\circ h=\operatorname{id}_{K^n}$, so that $f$ is surjective and $h$ injective. As these are endomorphisms of finite dimensional spaces, it amounts to saying they're isomorphisms, anf
$$ f\circ g\circ h=\operatorname{id}_{K^n}\Rightarrow f^{-1}\circ f\circ g\circ h\circ h^{-1}=g=f^{-1}\circ  h^{-1},$$
which proves $g$ is an isomorphism too, and $g^{-1}=h\circ  f. $

In terms ofmatrices: $A,B,C$  are invertible, and 
$$B^{-1}=CA$$
in addition to what could be deduced at once from the relation:
$$A^{-1}=BC, \quad C^{-1}=AB.$$